# Which two following statements are false?

Tags: matrices, inverse, transpose

Can someone explain to me the points iii , iv and v? I understand 1 and 2, but don't get the other 3.

Thank you!

[image: Matrices MC]

Comment: Do you know that $(AB)^t=B^tA^t$ and $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

For statement three, here is a hint: $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$.

It should be that $(A^TB^T)^T = BA$. Remember that $BA$ and $AB$ are not the same.